# Pausing a game in a java application

Tags: java

I am trying to add pause functionality to a game. Unfortunately the method I'm currently using causes the program to take no more inputs so I am unable to resume the game.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

a pause button calls:

```
public void pause(){
    if(data.paused == true){
        data.paused = false;
    }
    else{
        data.paused=true;
        while(true){
            if(data.paused == true){
                try{
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    System.out.println(ie);
                }
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        data.paused=false;
    }
  return;
```

I then have a TimerTask that I have to deal with:

```
class aTask extends java.util.TimerTask {
    protected Data data;
    public aTask( Data d ) { data = d; }
    public void run() { 
        try{ 
            if(data.paused){
                try{
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    System.out.println(ie);
                }
            }
            else
                data.tick(); 
        } 
        catch( ATCGameOverException e ){ 
            data.gameOver( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
};
```

where tick causes an action in the game every second.

I would think this would allow the game to pause when the button is pressed and then unpause when the button is pressed again, but I would be wrong.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `aTask` contains the game logic, if not what is this for? Where is game logic loop?

Comment: is this a 0-player game ? http://www.technicalypto.com/2011/08/conways-game-of-life-in-java.html is an example of a 0 player game which would require pause. If its 1 player, please show some more code.

Comment: why try to sleep, when you could just loop and check for pause state? I'm guessing you still may have to render the screen or save some sort of state in case of crash?

Comment: You can get help faster, if you add [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to your question.

Comment: Is this Swing and are you pausing the EDT (the Swing event thread)?

Comment: Answers to some of these questions for future viewers: yes aTask is the main manager for the game logic, no it is a 1 player game, @Chris Aldrich this is essentially the solution to my problem, yes it is using Swing and one of the sleeps was on the EDT unfortunately I was also pausing another thread... Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try this :

```
public void pause(){
  data.paused = !data.paused;
}
```

It looks like a threading problem. If you use Swing and your pause method is tied to an action listener, than the behaviour is normal: the pause function never returns, Swing main thread never has control again, and cannot manage further actions, including unpausing... Look at [this link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/)

My solution simply inverse the state of the pause variable, and gives control back to Swing. It's the game main loop that will tick the data or not according to the state of this variable. No thread is blocked, main loop continues to loop.

Comment: Hard to say if this is right or not as we haven't heard from the original poster yet, but it sounds good to me. 1+

Comment: "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" :D :D :D

Comment: thanks, this works, sorry I haven't been more responsive to this question, but this solution seems to work.  I can put in more details is it will help someone else.